# Bootstrap tabs not loading jQuery & Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tab pane using Bootstrap that I am attempting to load external pages into using Ajax via a jQuery script.

The ajax script is loading the pages' contents, however, the panes are not switching properly. They will load when I click on them, but they just "stick around," with the 2nd one stacking below the 1st pane when I click on it.

Here is the HTML (note, I am using Django, so the hrefs are Django lookups)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="caseTab">
            <li class="active">
                <a data-url="{% url 'person_case_list' person.id %}" href="#case_list">Case List</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-url="{% url 'pledge_list' person.id %}" href="#pledge_list">Pledge List</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="tab-pane active" id="case_list">

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane active" id="pledge_list">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript is:

```
<script>
$('#caseTab a').click(function (e) {
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    console.log(url);

    if(typeof url !== "undefined") {
        var pane = $(this), href = this.hash;
        $(href).load(url, function(result){
            pane.tab('show');
            if (window.jQuery){
                alert("Doing Number 1: jQuery working");
            } else {
                alert("Doing Number 1: jQuerty NOT working");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(this).tab('show');
        if (window.jQuery){
            alert("Doing number 2: jQuery Working");
        } else {
            alert("Doing number 2: jQuery NOT working");
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

The log `"Doing number 1: jQuery Working"` only fires when I click on tab 1 (`case_list`), but not every time. It will occasionally fire for tab 2 (`pledge_list`), but not usually.

The console is also logging the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function
```

This error appears to only fire for tab 2 (`pledge_list`), so far as I can tell. My `console.log` messages don't fire when this `Uncaught TypeError` fires.

Why does my `.click` function only catch sometimes? Why is `$(this).` not passing through properly?

Comment: I added in a check to see if Bootstrap was loaded during the load loop. It is loaded during my first click of either tab, but subsequently unloads completely, which causes `pane.tab` to not function properly.

Does anyone know why `bootstrap.js` would unload itself during a javascript loop?

Answer (score 2):

there is no functions `tab` in jQuery: try this example put only your url in data-url:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="caseTab">
        <li class="case_list" data-url="put your Url"><a href="#">Case List</a></li>
        <li class="case_list" data-url="put your Url"><a href="#">Pledge List</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="case_list">xx</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$('.case_list').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).data("url");
    $('#case_list').load(url);  
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This appears to work. Though it seems that it will only allow me to load remote url data, as there is only a single target div. So I can't have a mix of static content and dynamic content. Is that correct? Is there any way I can have multiple target divs? The `.tab` notation is from [bootstrap itself](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#javascript-behavior). My script includes the CDN for `bootstrap.min.js`, so I'm not sure why it isn't loading the function.

Answer (score 1):

Do you meen like this example? I hope that helped you.

```js
$('.nav-tabs>li>a').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('href'), url=$(this).data('url');
    $(id).load(url);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#aaa" data-url="put hier Url" data-toggle="tab">Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bbb" data-url="put hier Url" data-toggle="tab">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ccc" data-url="put hier Url" data-toggle="tab">Test3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="aaa">Content Test1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="bbb">Content Test2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">Content Test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: After a bit of tweaking, I was able to get this to work. It feels a bit hacky. After clicking on the tabs, it jumps to the top of the page, so I would have to hack it to remember the position instead of how tabs are supposed to work.

Here is the code that works:

$('.nav-tabs>li>a').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('href'), url=$(this).data('url');
    if(typeof url !== "undefined") {
        $(id).load(url);
        $(id).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(id).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
});

Comment: you don't need `$(id).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');` bootstrap do it already.

Comment: Sadly, that brings us back to the situation we had before where the previous tabs aren't unloading. Also, it is still causing the browser to jump to the top of the page whenever I click on a tab.

Comment: It jump to top only first time when you load or always?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Bootstrap, might jQuery UI's [tabs()](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) be of help, even with [external page loads](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/ajax.html)?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
        leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
        Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
        aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat.
        Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
        nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
      <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit,
        magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum
        rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```